# Impersonification and authorization in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, authorization

I'm using ASP.NET MVC with Windows Authentication and I'm wondering how to design an authorization for actions in controller. I use authorization based on AD groups. So access for an action in a controller is enabled only for users that has specific role. Is it possible to design some kind of impersonification that allows me to pretend I'm an another user without creating new account (using already existing account with assigned AD groups). It is only for testing a debuging purpose.
What is the best way to achieve this, or what would you recommend to me?